# Изменение константной переменной

Tags: c++, указатели, const

в main() написал следующее

```
int const a=10;  
int *p=(int*)(&a);     
*p=20;  
cout<< a << endl;  
cout<< *p << endl;  
return 0;
```

В отладчике наблюдаю изменение значения переменной **"a"** с 10 на 20. Но на экран выводится 10 и 20. То есть хоть и явно изменил константную переменную(знаю, что так нельзя делать, просто протестил) на экран вывелось прежнее значение. Запускал под виндой и под ubuntu на виртуалке. Почему же все-таки выводится 10 20, а не 20 20?

Comment: Потому что компилятор может соптимизировать константу и обращение к ней. Скомпилируйте код с разными уровнями оптимизаций,а еще лучше - сравните ассемблерные листинги

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Компилятор видит, что a - это константа. Значит, она поменятся не может (он на это имеет право рассчитывать). Соответсвенно, когда он видит вывод переменной a - он имеет законное право подставить готовое известное значение. То есть, компилятор преобразует это в такое

```
int const a=10;  
int *p=(int*)(&a);     
*p=20;  
cout<< 10 << endl;  
cout<< *p << endl;  
return 0;
```

И сколько переменная не меняется, значение будет все равно выводиться не то, которое Вы ожидаете.

Answer (score 4):

Компилятор "знает", что `a` не меняется, поэтому и выводит первоначальное значение.

Добавьте атрибут `volatile` (он говорит о том, что значение памяти может меняться независимо от создаваемого компилятором кода) и посмотрите:

```
volatile  int const a=10;  
 int *p=(int*)(&a);     
 *p=20;  
 cout<< a << endl;  
 cout<< *p << endl;  
 return 0;
```

теперь

```
avp@wubu:hashcode$ g++ tt.cpp && ./a.out 
20
20
avp@wubu:hashcode$
```

Comment: я может и фигню спрошу, но как компилятор вообще воспринимает `volatile const`? Т.е. константа которая не константа?..

Comment: @pavel, получается именно так. Все же `volatile` это иногда жизненно необходимо, а `const` по большому счету для любителей абстракций. Наверное, компилятору (хотя бы с флагами `-pedantic -Wall -Wextra`) в такой ситуации стоило бы вывести warning, но видимо "руки не дошли".

Comment: const - это хорошая штука - помогает подсказывать компилятору об оптимизациях и ожиданиях. А вот в примере выше компилятору сложно понять, что там изменяют константу. Хотя да, в этом конкретном примере он мог бы и догадаться, но можно же такой арифметики наворотить, что компилятор и за год не разберет.

Comment: @KoVadim, конечно, хотя в принципе, `const`  в отличии от `volatile`, вычисляем.  Очевидно поэтому `volatile` имеет бОльший вес.

Comment: C массовом получилось без volatile

Comment: @KoVadim, `const`, в общем случае на оптимизацию никак не влияет, т.к. компилятор не вправе считать `const` объект неизменным, если он не может этого доказать(причем совершенно точно)

Comment: @pavel, просто `const` в C/C++ это не совсем `const` в человеческом понимании. К примеру, есть у Вас просто `volatile` объект, который Вы хотите передать в функцию по константной ссылке. В этом случае есть смысл добавить `volatile`, я полагаю. Хотя я в своей практике никогда такого не встречал(правда я volatile не помню, чтобы встречал)

Comment: @ixSci мне кажется тут в комментариях путаются конст указатели/ссылки и константные объекты... Можете пояснить как можно поменять const переменную чтобы компилятор не мог воспользоваться правом на UB и не заинлайнить её?

Comment: @pavel, http://ideone.com/4f3Gd2. Cast away const не является UB само по себе

Answer (score 1):

C массивом прокатило без volatile. изменил и вывел изменённое значение

```
const int arr[2][2]={{1,2},{3,4}};
int *p=(int *)((arr[1]+1));

cout<<"before"<<endl;
cout<<"*p        = "<<*p<<endl;
cout<<"arr[1][1] = "<<arr[1][1]<<endl;
cout<<"after"<<endl;
*p=60;
cout<<"*p        = "<<*p<<endl;
cout<<"arr[1][1] = "<<arr[1][1]<<endl;
return 0;
```

Comment: У с++ есть много способов обмануть компилятор. И много способов себя пристрелить. Но нужно ли это делать? Всегда помните о простой вещи - не пытайтесь обмануть компилятор, иначе он поймет это и накажет.